# Indefinite integral of $\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}$, is my solution needlessly complicated?

Tags: calculus, integration

This took awhile and since I am hoping to be able to compute these quickly in an exam setting I am hoping for a simpler way.

Using the substitution $x=\sin^2t$ gets me:
$$
I/2=\int \frac{\sin^2t+2}{\sqrt{4\sin^2t-\sin^4t}}\sin t\cos t dt\\
I/2=\int \frac{\sin^2t+2}{\sin t\sqrt{4-\sin^2t}}\sin t\cos t dt=
\int \frac{\sin^2t+2}{\sqrt{4-\sin^2t}}\cos t dt\\
=1/2\int\frac{\sin^2t+2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\sin^2t}{4}}}\cos t dt\\
\Rightarrow I=\int\frac{\sin^2t+2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\sin^2t}{4}}}\cos t dt
$$
Where I can now substitute $u=\sin(t)/2\Rightarrow du=1/2\cos tdt$ which at least gets rid of the $\cos$, yielding
$$
I=2\int\frac{u^2/2+2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} du=\int\frac{u^2+4}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
$$

Which I can now evaluate with another trig substitution. Wolfram gives a very complicated answer but it seems to not be great at trig substitutions for these integrals. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The second substitution $u=sin(t)/2$ in the numerator of the integrand appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus caught it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $\displaystyle\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{4-2x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}dx+4\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}}dx$;

letting $u=4x-x^2$ in the first integral and $t=x-2$ in the second gives

$\displaystyle-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du+4\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt=-\sqrt{4x-x^2}+4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right)+C$

Answer (score 5):

The integral can be evaluated as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}\,dx&=\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{4-\left(x-2\right)^2}}\,dx\\[5pt]
&=\int\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{4-\left(x-2\right)^2}}\,dx+\int\frac{4}{\sqrt{4-\left(x-2\right)^2}}\,d(x-2)\\[5pt]
&=-\frac12\frac{\left(4-\left(x-2\right)^2\right)^{1/2}}{1/2}+4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-2}2\right)+C\\[5pt]
&=4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x-2}2\right)-\sqrt{4x-x^2}+C
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah I always forget completing the square. Thank you that was exactly what i needed and matches the solution in the book.

Comment: @qbert You're welcome.

Comment: I will accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: Also, why did you write $d(x-2)$ on the second line?

Comment: @qbert It is the same that writing $$\int\frac{4}{\sqrt{4-(x-2)^2}}\,dx=4\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2-u^2}}du$$
with the sustitution $u=x-2$, in order to apply the formula $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}\,du=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+C$$

Comment: Right but did you do a substitution on that line, it seemed to me you are just splitting into two fractions

Comment: @qbert Yes, I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41590/discussion-between-qbert-and-angel-mario-gallegos).

Answer (score 2):

When I see radicals, I try to get rid of them as quickly as I can.

So, let us try $$4x-x^2=u^2\implies x=\sqrt{4-u^2}+2\implies dx=-\frac{u}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}\,du$$ $$I=\int \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}\,dx=-\int\frac{\sqrt{4-u^2}+4}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}\,du=-\int\left(1+\frac{4}{\sqrt{4-u^2}} \right)\,du$$ Now, for the last integral $u=2v$ leads to a simple, well know, integral